# Selenium webdriver on Node.js - how to access global window variable

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Node.js App, selenium webdriver, Chrome headless.
My app needs to scrape a list of websites and one of them has attached information to global window variable.

I have tried the following and it throws an error:

```
// .... more code to load page up to this point

driver.execute(function () {
    console.log(window.info);
    return window;
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log( "\n\ninfo from window object: " + util.inspect(result) );
}).catch( (err) => {
    console.error(" Caught Error for window: " + err);
});

// throws ERROR:  Caught Error for window: TypeError: command.setParameter is not a function
```

Is there a way to access the global window variable from Selenium (preferably headless, but if I should use head then I can try that) ?

Answer (score 3):

nevermind, I found the answer.

the method is executeScript() and not execute().

```
driver.executeScript("return window.info")
      .then(function (result) {
            console.log( "\n\ninfo from window object: " + util.inspect(result) );
      }).catch( (err) => {
        console.error(" Caught Error for window: " + err);
      });
```